"Infantry" main weapons for the setting described below? (NOT a duplicate for reasons explained in the post)
(before anybody decide to flag this post as a duplicate, there's an explanation of why it looks identical at the bottom of this post)
what would be a suitable choice for "infantries"(the quote unquote is because it's not necessarily a real person, possibly just a rover with a gun doing the job of a foot soldier) for this following setting? the general background, especially the technology, is a bit messy with a mix of near, mid and far-future tech that I'll attempt to outline below (for example a capital ship in the setting belonging might have a antimatter beam-core engine while it's missiles are methalox/Metallic Hydrogen rockets launched from a coilgun and communicating with other ships with lasers then getting a reply with neutrinos)
assumptions:
1: The function of the civilization being discussed (hereby referred to as the state)'s infantry is much like today's, namely fighting in buildings, tunnels, forests etc where armor and artillery is either unavailable or need their support, alongside with holding these regions and general low-intensity engagements
2: The opponent is also human, however as they're interstellar colonists who had no contact with the state for roughly three hundred years, the state is as familiar with them as the Aztecs are familiar with the conquistadors. They relies on infantry far more than it does on armored vehicle or artillery (if this sounds awfully world war 1 to you, you're absolutely correct, because the vast majority of their wars are either purely space combat or really didn't call for more than infantry). They have little automation so robotic enemies are out of the question. Their infantry is protected either very poorly with little to no protection at all, with heavy armor that would be considered NIJ standard type IV armor by modern standards, or force fields that could be depleted with 20 hit from 12.7s while being armed with star wars Blaster-like weapons. Their force fields could stop a single EMP or electrocution attack by taking it for whatever it is protecting and getting disabled as a result.
3: The infantry (alongside with anything that is intended to be used on the surface) is deployed using Project Orion style dropships capable of landing with large payloads around 200 tons. However due to the fallout of detonating nuclear devices as thrust, the infantry may only leave while inside their IFV or APCs (which also means that unless otherwise specified, the infantry is always expected to have their vehicle somewhere nearby to support them)
4: The state as a whole utilizes only technology that would be considered unobtanium at most (for example a Kerr-Newman black hole on a vessel is fair play but a lightsaber is not), handwavium is avoided with the possible exception of negative mass
5: while most of the fighting is on shirt-sleeve habitable planets, it is also required to be able to function in non-habitable environments such as a methane atmosphere (though it does not have to function in vacuum)
6: The state considers it's army (space force not included) to be largely expendable in the sense that they would try to force the enemy into attrition warfare if it believe it could win one, does not care much about public relationships (this is after all a totalitarian regime), and draws from a larger overall manpower/resource pool than it's opponents possibly could. However when on the offensive they tend to have less units immediately available due to having rather expensive transport costs, therefore superior individual performance is desirable
7: the state has very capable and portable power sources that could be scaled down to infantry use in the range of 10-30 megajoules per kilogram
8: Powered armor(or exoskeleton, depending on how yo classify them) exists, they could provide a large amount of power to the soldier's equipment if it requires any, and the state could afford to equip a large amount of it's soldiers with them. However they are much less capable than Battle Brothers or anything like that. They are capable of boosting mobility and firepower but anything that will cause a individual soldier to be heavier than 235KG will not be accepted, in order to not collapse the floor/stair they might be standing on (if they can't enter a building safely than there's no reason for them, why not bring in a tank?). They only provide armor in critical areas such as the chest, and no radiological protection beyond what is expected from a HAZMAT suit (although this does make them impervious to chemical weapons). On the other hand they are notably un-bulky compared to the traditional image of powered armor, appearing simply to be a slightly higher soldier (the closest example I can think of is Iron Man)
In response to the situation being described above, what could the state's infantry be primarily armed with? (just the "assault rifle", more specialized weapons such as anti-armor is a totally different issue, which I also happen to be more confident in)
(Disclaimer: This post looks near-identical with a previous post that I made, because the previous one started off as a ridiculously unfocused question(scroll down to see how horrible the original one was). It was closed for understandable reasons after commentors explained to me why it is a terrible post, so I edited it into the current shape that you see above, however there is not enough voters to reopen the original post (at that time, at GMT june 19th the original post was reopened). I still need a answer, since the previous post was closed before any agreeable answer came by although the suggestions on how to make a good question did get incorporated, but I can't just delete a post with upvoted answers either. So after flagging the original post and getting advised by either a moderator or a senior member to repost it with clear explanations, here we are)

FYI: landing with an Orion drive is a Very Bad Idea. Even using them for deceleration in an atmosphere is inadvisable.

@StarfishPrime if you’re referring to the problem of flying into it’s own nuclear fireball, then I’m aware of that problem, though I decided to use an Orion anyways because as a dropship it have to be heavily armored in the first place so having a massive armored pusher plate with the mass budget of everything from armor to landing gear to take the blasts seem acceptable. Secondly in the atmosphere there’s shockwaves so a much smaller nuke can be used

Multiple nukes in the atmosphere.....There's also the radioactive consequences to the atmosphere and life on the planet.

[7: the state has very capable and portable power sources that could be scaled down to infantry use in the range of 10-30 megajoules per kilogram] This is half as good as diesel fuel. Great for batteries, but not really a game changer.

@gs yeah, it's not that powerful compared to diesel, I said it's "Very capable" in comparison to modern batteries with ~0.36MJ/kg) it's mentioned because it would allow quite a few interesting infantry weapons such as lasers and coilguns to be more practical

@Escapeddentalpatient. well lets just say they are not exactly environmental conservatives)

Orion in the atmosphere wouldn't be too bad if you could use laser triggers and jacket them in something that will harmlessly deal with the neutrons.  (The lasers stay on the lander, not with the bomb.)  However, landing one brings to mind the term "suicide burn".  At a minimum you need some very big, very tough legs because the pusher plate can't get too close to the ground.

@LorenPechtel on that, I think you've inspired some thought from me. In this setting pure fusion devices exist (triggered by metastable metallic hydrogen explosives), even though the D-T fusion reaction is neutronic, the metallic hydrogen chemical explosives should leave behind quite some hydrogen that can absorb a neutron to become deuterium, which is totally harmless.  Perhaps this design could work as a quasi-aneutronic fusion bomb(quasi because I'm expecting some neutrons to not ram a hydrogen) that can be used on the Orion lander without committing ecocide?

@General_Ripper Metallic hydrogen isn't going to even be in the ballpark of enough energy.  You need to crush it with forces in the terapascal range.  A quick search seems to show chemical explosives only go up to about 50 gigapascals.  (And deuterium isn't totally harmless, it's just the toxic level is way, way above what you see in nature.  Drinking too much D2O is not advised, but your lander wouldn't create enough to matter.)

@LorenPechtel I see your point here, though perhaps this article's suggested methods of    concentrating the energy of the high explosive shockwaves in some manner (I'm not exactly an expert so my paraphrasing is probably incorrect) could adress that? on the other hand the laser ignition scheme you suggested seems already good enough https://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/supplement/Impact%20Fusion%20Write-Up.pdf

@General_Ripper I'm aware of that article.  Note that that proposed device does not use chemical explosives to compress the fusion target.  It uses chemical explosives to compress a magnetic flux which compresses the target.  The chemical explosives come nowhere near the energy density required.

@General_Ripper And I find myself very puzzled about the secondary in their device.  It appears to be using the normal approach of reflecting the energy of the primary in on the secondary to achieve the required compression--but in a Teller-Ulam design there's also a plutonium rod that gets crushed and actually ignites it.  I see no igniter and if it's being initiated entirely from the energy from the primary there's no reason it couldn't have multiple stages the same way a Teller-Ulam design works.  Thus there should be no yield limit.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Only 200 tons for your Orion Drive landers? Even 1960s technology could produce Orion Drives that could take 6000 tons to the Moon and back on one tank of fuel.

@nick012000 these examples are actually able to land? I thought being unable to land was the whole reason why the orion warship had shuttles and all these mentionings about flying into their own fireballs

Saying this is not a duplicate doesn't make it so: if this is a copy of your former question, I urge you to remain patient and keep working at it, that's why the rules of this community are there.

Does this answer your question? "Infantry" main weapons for the setting described below?

@Joachim well technically, the old question got closed first, then I worked on edits to make it into it's current shape, but at that point nobody's coming to vote it back so I flagged it to ask for a moderator to  delete it, and the lad that came to me basically explicitly told me to repost this with explanations. Also, the old question got closed before I got a answer that I think is reasonable enough so it does not really answer my question beyond suggesting to me improvements that went into the current shape https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/111226?showDeclined=true

Users have come back to vote - at least, I've seen it come by in the Reopen queue, but thought it still wasn't ready. But if this has been discussed with a moderator, I'll retract my vote here, although I'd urge that moderator to be transparent about the process, as it's still not the way these things are handled on this platform. As for not receiving a (satisfactory) answer: that's the entire point :) Questions that don't meet the requirements are closed to prevent them from being answered, so the asker has an incentive to put more effort into their post.

@Joachim I understand, I'll try to avoid future mistakes like the one that caused ths whole mess in the future, thanks for pointing out the part about transparency

Aside from the obvious questions around "why are you using infantry" and "why aren't you using appropriate weapons for the environment; surely an interstellar multi-planetary industrial base for a civilization apparently happy to wage war on a similar scale can manage a reasonable logistics chain", it seems to me that the most general-purpose weapon format is probably small self-propelled projectiles.
It is hard to tell exactly what sort of tech-level you're after here because your setting is so inconsistent... beam-core rockets side by side with methalox rockets? Do your ground forces use stone-throwing artillery, still?
Anyway, self-propelled projectiles get a bit of a bad rap in the real world because of the failure of gyrojets, but everyone seems to forget that they were invented and trialled in the sixties and technology has marched on a bit since then even in the real world, let alone in a warlike interstellar civilization.
Lets imagine these small rockets are under 20mm in diameter. You probably want more like 10mm for strictly antipersonnel use (less overkill, easier to carry more rounds), but you might have multi-purpose double-barrelled weaponry, or squad-level heavier weapons, maybe with larger-bore projectiles.
Micro-missiles offer a number of useful features, such as:

can work in a wide range of atmospheres, including no atmosphere at all.
reduces complexity of gun, making it more robust especially in the presence of hostile atmospheres.
works even in opaque atmospheres (eg. dust clouds, fog, smoke) which seriously hinder beam weapons.
no dependency on high-capacity, high-discharge-rate power packs.
minimal cooling issues.
minimal recoil, making it convenient for use in microgravity environments.
potential to mount a variety of different warheads, or use kinetic penetrators.
potential to do mid-course guidance.

The latter two are the most interesting ones, and where this diverges from the Space Marine style. Being able to do stuff like beam-riding, or autonomous target tracking, or simply replay a course programmed at firing time gives you a very versatile weapon that can do a bunch of novel things that regular projectiles and beams weapons cannot:

limited ability to fire "around corners"... useful in some kinds of rotating-wheel style space station, but also useful for trajectory correction in any kind of environment where artificial gravity is provided by rotation, and coriolis effects make regular projectiles much harder to use (I've written an answer on this subject in the past).
ability to trade off range to maintain a flat trajectory to make aiming easier, even in bad weather, very thick atmospheres or under elevated gravitational fields (or on spacecraft undergoing high accelerations).
ability to trade off projectile velocity for stealth, keeping rounds subsonic over long ranges, hindering detection of the shooter.
potential for beam-riding guidance for very high accuracy, even against (probably slow) moving targets.
separate spotters or targetting drones or devices let users shoot targets they can't even see.
active warheads of various kinds mean lethality is the same at any range, regardless of projectile velocity.
ability to air-burst a fragmentation warhead at a specific range to attack targets in cover.
armor-piercing warheads for tough targets like light vehicles, or armored exoskeletons
non armor-piercing warheads for use in fragile, hazardous environments like some kinds of space station or spacecraft.
specialist warheads for specific circumstances, like incendiary, chemical weapons, EMP, miniature antipersonnel mines, flares, smoke, harsh language, etc.

The approach scales well with future technologies, taking advantages of improvements in miniaturized guidance systems or novel warhead types (fullerene-encapsulated antimatter, anyone? maybe an antimatter-driven single-pulse gamma ray laser?).
Loadouts can be tailored to the mission and the role of the person using the gun, perhaps with some emergency use special rounds to help cover a retreat from unexpected resistance, and so on.
I still hold that thinking about infantry at all is perhaps the ultimate "fighting the last war" in this situation, and your starship troopers would probably all be annihilated by autonomous antipersonnel drone swarms that will probably be coming to a real-world battlefield in the depressingly near future, but that aside: micromissile launchers seem to be sufficiently versatile that they can slot into a one-size-fits-all weapon category for your setting.

Thanks for the answer, I'll see if I can work out some more environment specific weapons. regarding the drones, while I do think that they're the future, there's this pesky Burnside's Zeroth Law about how audiences relate much more to humans than silicon chips) So I had to skew the setting's data security to the point that virtually anything not in a faraday cage and electronic can be hacked to some extent. Also, the "beam-core and methalox" problem's in-universe reason is that antimatter's hard to store in a tiny rocket while still being affordable enough to throw away in barrages.

@General_Ripper ok fine, but methalox? Given all the other technological achievements, all those lasers and nukes and force fields, and you’ve got rocketry out of the twenties? That’s the best alternative to antimatter?

good point) I'll check if there's better options. In setting there's basically two types of space missiles, the first is uber-cheap barrage missiles that use saturation to overwhelm point defences, for these I think metallic hydrogen-based chemical rockets might be suitable. On the other hand there's pseudo-stealth ones with cryogenic surfaces, RCS-reducing designs and vanta-black coating to drastically reduce detection ranges, for these one they can be much more expensive so I'm looking at expansion-cooled NTRs. Do these sound a bit more fitting?

Self-propelled projectiles do have innate limitations, and not just because the first trials in the sixties used less advanced technology. Unless all (or most of the) acceleration happens inside the barrel of the gun, it will be extremely weak at close range. And if all acceleration happens inside the barrel, then it is an explosive, not a rocket, so why have a rocket at all? What problem do you want to solve with it? Just to have simpler reloading, and fire the entire thing at the enemy? Caseless ammunition does exist for this exact purpose, but has the problem of overheating.

@vsz there is, in fact, a list of perceived benefits in this very answer.

Firstly - Love the new question - I can see you took my feedback on board and the new question is much better.
The key things that jump out at me are:
1: Not expected to need heavy fire support (e.g. engaging enemy vehicles, Troops are not heavily armored, not a lot of bunkers etc.)
2: They are expected to be delivered in drop pods and then in an APC or other armored type vehicle.
3: Their enemy is expected to be numerous, but poorly armed and armored.
4: Power Armor is more of a specialist tool than standard issue.
So firstly - let us talk range - your combat environment is expected to be Buildings, Forrests and Tunnels - so for starters, we are going to be sacrificing Range - what is the point of having a weapon system that is lethal out to 10 kilometres when your sight-lines are at most 100 metres (adjust your actual sight-lines as necessary)
Next up we have our Enemy - Since we are fighting a lot of infantry who are lightly armoured - having smart weapons is less of a concern. Smart weapons have a cost to them (in terms of manufacturing and other) - you typically see that as the target value goes up, so does the smartness of the weapon system.
It makes little sense to use something like a smart homing rocket on some poor sap who has no body-armor, when a simple projectile or beam weapon would suffice.
What we are going to be considered about is the ability to make rapid follow-up shots, large ammunition capacity - and since you mentioned that the state is totalitarian - I am going to make the presumption that they take the Canadian View: Geneva Suggestions or the Geneva Check-list... So things like indiscriminate fire or collateral casualties aren't a concern.
If we are using projectile based weaponary, then we have to contend with recoil (which we don't want).
Next up is the weapon itself - this is an interesting one - as a primarily mechanized force, we have the possibility that we could have a weapon that is heavier than a typical rifle (This could mean more energy cells, more ammunition, more do-dads, or if we go the projectile route - heavier weapon = less recoil).
However, again, if we look at our expected areas of operation (Tunnels, buildings Forests) we want something small and nimble so that we quickly clear corners and rooms etc.
In terms of Power - your power cells - 10-30 MJ of energy per Kilo, an M1 Abrams tank round has a Muzzle energy 12 MJ, and the lowly .223 cartridge has a Muzzle energy of around 1.7 KJ - 1,000 rounds of .223 ammo is around 14 Kilos (depending on projectile weight) - so call 100 rounds 1.4 Kilos - doing some quick and dirty maths - a 1 Kg Power cell in your universe is a lot of .223 equivalent ammo.
Finally, we want a system that can be integrated with their APC to operate in hostile environments.
Mixing that all together:
We want a Weapon where the functional bit that goes in the hand is short and easy to point. We want minimal recoil and we want the ability to fire a lot. We are not super concerned with the over-all weight of the weapons system as we our expecting our troops not to be doing too much walking. We are probably looking at an Energy based system as we can get plenty of bang for a given weight. We aren't looking for Smart weaponary per se as that is overkill, we aren't worried about range either because our expected engagement distances are very short.
I think we would see some form of Back-pack mounted, flame-thrower esque (Plasma thrower?) system.
Being an all-electric system means that we aren't worried about things like explosives transport or ammunition cook-offs.
We could also have it integrate with the APCs like the old AK rifles did on the BMPs where the backpack component could be stored in the APC, and the nozzle part would be put through a sealed port.
The State isn't worried about things like War Crimes or indiscriminate damage - in fact, if it is totalitarian in nature - it might even favor the terror aspect of a high-tech stream of plasma vaporizing parts of an enemy (Psychological warfare is still a thing - Even on the modern Battlefield, if you hear the Brits call to Fix Bayonets, shit is about to get stabby).
Using a standard power cell would be great for logistics (Just like builders and their tools use a standard power cell) allowing 'ammo' to be shared between squadmates or even other areas like maintenance or engineering.
Finally - given your World War 1 inspiration having a modern Flammenwerfer suits the aesthetics (especially if you give your infantry gasmasks for Rule-of-cool)

regarding the "armor is infrequent“ part, I think I might not have described it very accurately because tanks and APCs and all that still pop up every now and then, it's just that they are not a frequent encounter. therefore, I think the part about flammenwerfers probably make more sense with specialist breakthrough units than with being the equivalent of assault rifles.  OTOH that's more of my mistake than yours so I'm still gonna upvote this answer

@General_Ripper - I see - I mean on the modern battlefield anti-armour is dealt with by a Heavy Weapon Squad within a platoon (I think)

you're not wrong on that, my point is that since the enemy is also armored to some extent (not enough to make them immune to flamethrowers, but some) and retaining the ability to strike from ~400m and/or deal damage on a more localized scale (burning everybody is awesome, but every now and them they're a bit too close to burn without hurting the user) is a good thing, it might be better to keep flamethrowers as specialist weapons, just more common than others

Fighting in atmosphere you need weapons the don't bloom that rules out most lasers, plasma, and most or all particle weapons, even the ultra relativistic electron beam that is famously low bloom, and low divergence, in a vacuum doesn't work in atmosphere. That leaves you with projectile weapons and lasers at frequencies that don't interact much with the air. That's microwave and gamma ray lasers, coil and rail guns, gyrojets and modern fire arms. All of those weapons are going to have issues in atmospheres with notable amounts of free Methane or Ethyne so I would think that any infantry weapons are going to have light weight blast shields, probably polycarbonate or similar, that can be fitted to them for operations in "reactive" atmospheres. The extremely high frequencies of the laser weapons is going to be a terribly inefficient use of energy. Coilguns have issues with complex timing, current transmission density, and thermal loading problems. Railguns have those same issues plus rail erosion (I have seen a cool schematic for clip feeding rounds complete with single use rails). Gyrojets have major ammunition density issues but could potentially make good failsafe weapons for use inside pressure hulls.
My first instinct is to go with modern firearms using caseless ammunition, it's a reliable and mature technology that works acceptably in almost any conditions, there are already types of ammunition and calibres that won't over penetrate, and that will penetrate human (or even tank) portable armour etc...

Lasers with even quite modest apertures can get a tight focus over the whole range that infantry generally fight at. Electron beams and ultrashort laser pulses both self-focus in atmospheres. I'm not sure why you think gamma ray lasers don't interact with the atmosphere. Reducing atmospheres can't be explosive (because vulcanism or lightning will have sparked it off by now) so I'm not sure what you're thinking a "reactive atmosphere" will be doing?

regarding the part about lasers, according to this link 400nm violet and 480nm cyan works pretty well in the atmosphere, while gamma rays get stopped quite frequently. Also, if my setting already have shipborne and energetically efficient coilguns and lasers (~80% for ultraviolet lasers and ~99.5% for coilguns)  does that also imply a lot of the problems you mentioned about them could be solved?https://projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/sidearmenergy.php#laseratmo

@General_Ripper That is very much going to depend on the composition of atmosphere in question, there are just better uses for the power, like running a sealed muscle amplification suit.

@StarfishPrime .A reactive atmosphere is not possible on a world without life, nor is it stable over geological time on the only world with life that we know of, that doesn't mean it can't be an issue.

@Ash yeah, though on the other hand in this question the setting's infantry primarily fights in shirt-sleeves or habitats, so expecting a atmosphere that is somewhat similar to earth is ok

@Ash About the power part, I have no idea how to estimate moving somebody around's energy expenditure, but a human body expends ~6 megajoules per day based on these figures in the link below and assuming 62kg of weight, which is still easily coverable by the energy sources mentioned in the assumptions. if we assume the 6MJ includes exercise then there should be plenty of power left for other powerhogs http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2012/ph240/khan1/#:~:text=The%20basic%20energy%20consumption%20of%20the%20human%20body,KJ%20%C3%97%2024%20hours%2Fday%20%2F%204.18%20kJ%20%281%29

A reducing atmosphere would require its own explanation. Naturally (i.e. without life) planets have an atmosphere of the most abundant gasses and chemical leftovers from its forming phase. Smaller planets lose the lighter gasses, so CO2 and Nitrogen dominate.The most reactive gasses found on planets are ammonia and sulfuric acids and only in trace amounts. Free oxygen is the exception. It only exists because carbon based life decided that freeing the C from CO2 was worth the enormous energy expense. And that was only possible because the invention of photosynthesis created an energy abundance.
